# $A\in M_{3\times3} $ has eigenvalues $\lambda=1,-1. \Rightarrow A^3=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My first intuition was that the statement in the title is false, however I have failed to find a counterexample. Iv'e managed to show this is true if $A$ is diagonalizable but cannot see why this is necessarily true.
Thanks.

Clarification: $\lambda=1,-1$ are the only eigenvalues

Comment: Are these the ONLY eigen values?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the question to make that clear

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This confirms the statement, what's the use?

Comment: @Math_QED I don't think so.

Comment: Ah I thought it was diagonal. I missed the 1 on position (12)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}^3=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&1&3\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

(The minimal polynomial for this is $x^3-x^2-x+1$, and if it cubed to the identity, it would have to satisfy $x^3-1$.)

Answer (score 4):

With Jordan decomposition you have these two possibilities (among others) :
$\exists P\in Gl_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A=P\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1&0 \\ 0 & 1&0\\0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$ or $A=P\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1&0 \\ 0 & -1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$.
For example in the first case we have $A\neq A^3$.

Comment: Nothing is incorrect, but it might be good to say "two possiblities (but not only two)" to avoid someone interpreting it that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is false
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}^3=\begin{bmatrix}1&6&3\\0&1&1\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$